# Can a function be used to redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

so I have a developing a trivia game and I have am trying to have a function redirect to a page that tells them if the answer was correct or not. Below shows what I have going on.

My functions to check the answers that the end user inputed.

```js
function Question(stem, answer, type){
    this.stem = stem; 
    this.answer = new Array(rowLimit);
    this.answer.push(answer);
    this.type = type;
}
function score(userAnswer){
    var result = "";
    console.log("Data returning for this.answer: " + this.answer);
    var lowerUserAnswer = userAnswer.toLowerCase().trim();

    for(var a = 2;  a < this.answer.length; a++){
        lowerAnswer = this.answer[a].trim().toLowerCase();
      
        if (type == 1) { // this is a true / false question
            console.log('Inside type 1');
            result = trueFalseResponses(lowerUserAnswer, lowerAnswer);
        } else if (type == 2) {// single word question
            console.log('Inside type 2');
            result = singleWordResponses(lowerUserAnswer, lowerAnswer);
        } else if (type == 3){ // sentence question
            console.log('Inside type 3');
            result = sentenceResponses(lowerUserAnswer, lowerAnswer);
        } else {
            console.log('Inside of else');
            console.log("Question type is needed.");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
function trueFalseResponses(userInput, realAnswer){
   if(userInput.charAt(0) == realAnswer.charAt(0)) {
        console.log('Inside of if trueFalseResponses');
        correctAnswerIncrease();
    }
   else {
        console.log('Inside of else trueFalseResponses');
        incorrectAnswerIncrease();
    }
   return "";
}
function singleWordResponses(userInput, realAnswer){
   if(userInput === realAnswer) {
        console.log('Inside of if singleWordResponses');
        correctAnswerIncrease();
   }
   else {
        console.log('Inside of else singleWordResponses');
        incorrectAnswerIncrease();
   }
   return "";
}
function sentenceResponses(userInput, realAnswer){
   if(userInput.includes(realAnswer)) {
        console.log('Inside of if sentenceResponses');
        correctAnswerIncrease();
   }
   else {
        console.log('Inside of else sentenceResponses');
        incorrectAnswerIncrease();
   }
   return "";
}
function correctAnswerIncrease (req, res, next){
    console.log('Inside of if correctAnswerIncrease');
    incremented = incremented + 1;
    soulTracker = soulTracker + 1;
    res.redirect('/correct');
}
function incorrectAnswerIncrease(req, res, next){
    console.log('Inside of if incorrectAnswerIncrease');
    res.send('/incorrect');
    incremented = incremented + 1;
```

Web pages that tells them if the response was correct or not...

```js
app.get('/correct', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('correct');
});
app.get('/incorrect', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('incorrect');
});
app.post('/correct', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('correct');
});
app.post('/incorrect', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('incorrect');
});
```

So when the answer is inputed, depending on the type of response the question can take, it's passed from score, to the question type which is either `trueFalseResponses`, `singleWordResponses`, or `sentenceResponses`. If the response was correct, or incorrect, I want the page to redirect them to `/correct` or `/incorrect`. However, when I attempted that, I received the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'redirect')

I have tried to use `window.location.href`, `window.location.href` and `window.location.replace` but that has not helped as well. The goal is to redirect them to `/correct` or `/incorrect` if the response from the user was correct or incorrect.

Comment: `window.location = "/correct"` or `window.location = "/incorrect"` in your browser Javascript will work just fine to change the current displayed web page as long as the code isn't part of a form post that will itself also change the web page to a new location.

Comment: From a request handler on an Express server, you would do `res.redirect("/correct)`, but not if the request is in response to an Ajax call because Ajax calls don't cause the web browser to change what they display.  That redirect would just go back to your web page javascript where the web page javascript would have to do the redirect client-side.

Comment: Is your first block of code client code or server code?

Comment: Hello jfriend00, all code shown is in the Server code. No code is apart of the form.

Comment: I attempted window.location = "/correct" or window.location = "/incorrect" but got the following error... "ReferenceError: window is not defined".

Comment: As I said, `window.location = xxx` is for Javascript in the browser, NOT Javascript on the server.  You need be very clear about which code runs on the server and which code runs in the browser and code them accordingly.  `window.location` can ONLY be used in code that runs in the browser, not code that runs on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up restructuring the code by making the following changes.

The codes below became booleans.

```
function score(userAnswer){
var result = "";
console.log("Data returning for this.answer: " + this.answer);
var lowerUserAnswer = userAnswer.toLowerCase().trim();

for(var a = 2;  a < this.answer.length; a++){
    lowerAnswer = this.answer[a].trim().toLowerCase();
  
    if (type == 1) { // this is a true / false question
        console.log('Inside type 1');
        result = trueFalseResponses(lowerUserAnswer, lowerAnswer);
    } else if (type == 2) {// single word question
        console.log('Inside type 2');
        result = singleWordResponses(lowerUserAnswer, lowerAnswer);
    } else if (type == 3){ // sentence question
        console.log('Inside type 3');
        result = sentenceResponses(lowerUserAnswer, lowerAnswer);
    } else {
        console.log('Inside of else');
        console.log("Question type is needed.");
    };
    console.log('Result from score is ' + result);
    if (result === true) {
        soulTracker += 1;
        incremented += 1;
    } else {
        incremented += 1;
    };
    return result;
}}

function trueFalseResponses(userInput, realAnswer){
   if(userInput.charAt(0) == realAnswer.charAt(0)) {
        console.log('Inside of if trueFalseResponses');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('Inside of else trueFalseResponses');
        return false;
    }}

function singleWordResponses(userInput, realAnswer){
   if(userInput === realAnswer) {
        console.log('Inside of if singleWordResponses');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('Inside of else singleWordResponses');
        return false;
    }}

function sentenceResponses(userInput, realAnswer){
   if(userInput.includes(realAnswer)) {
        console.log('Inside of if sentenceResponses');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('Inside of else sentenceResponses');
        return false;
    }}
```

I also made the following changes to my post method.

```
app.post('/triviaquestions', (req, res, next) => {
if (score(req.body.triviaResponse) === true){
    console.log('Inside of if score = true');
    res.redirect('/correct');
}
else {
    console.log('Inside of if score = false');
    res.redirect('/incorrect');
}});
```

These changes turned out to be successful.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
function sentenceResponses(userInput, realAnswer){
   if(userInput.includes(realAnswer)) {
        console.log('Inside of if sentenceResponses');
        correctAnswerIncrease();
   }
   else {
        console.log('Inside of else sentenceResponses');
        incorrectAnswerIncrease();
   }
   return "";
}
```

You call either `correctAnswerIncrease()` or `incorrectAnswerIncrease()`, but those two functions expect multiple parameters to be passed to them:

```
function correctAnswerIncrease (req, res, next){
    console.log('Inside of if correctAnswerIncrease');
    incremented = incremented + 1;
    soulTracker = soulTracker + 1;
    res.redirect('/correct');
}
function incorrectAnswerIncrease(req, res, next){
    console.log('Inside of if incorrectAnswerIncrease');
    res.send('/incorrect');
    incremented = incremented + 1;
}
```

Thus, when you try to use `res` inside those functions, you get an error because the caller didn't pass `res` and thus they are `undefined`.  When you call a function, you MUST pass the arguments that the function expects.

In addition `incorrectAnswerIncrease()` probably should be `res.redirect('/incorrect')`, not `res.send('/incorrect')`.

---

I might also mention that it appears you're using server-wide variables here like `incremented` and `soulTracker`.  That will work only if all users are supposed to share the same variables.  If these are supposed to be user-specific variables, this will not work as all users will be sharing the same variables.

Comment: > you're using server-wide variables here
I'll add to this that even if they're shared across all users, there's still a risk of losing the data or corrupting the data (e.g. if you have multiple instances). Better to use a persistent storage mechanism than store in memory.

Comment: right, that's the next thing to be worked on once I resolve this issue. So what's a better way to redirect the page to another page without using res? I am running the code on the server, not the browser.

Comment: @JonD - You can't redirect the user from the server without `res`.  You have to pass `res` to any function that needs to redirect so it can use `res.redirect()`.

Comment: Which I figured, so should I make req pass as a boolean in this instance or something?

Comment: @JonD - You don't show where this code originates in a request handler (where `req`, `res` and `next` come from when these functions are called) so it's not clear how this should be be structured.  I've explained to you the problem.  You need to restructure your code so that `res` can be passed to any function that wants to do a redirect of the function can return it's value instead and the request handler can get that return value and then decide what redirect to do.  That second option is my general preference.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean the more I look at the code. I am currently attempting revisions.